# How to specify container's name in Swarm for --volumes-from option

Tags: docker, swarm

Using standalone containers I run a cronjob with

```
docker run -name my_name --volumes-from container_name ...
```

I want to do the same in a Swarm stack, where my service have more that one replicas, so containers name are container_name.1., container_name.2., etc.

How to specify container's name not to change it each time after container restarting when it gets new id?

Answer (score 0):

Docker Swarm creates a stack with named services, and the services create containers that are disposable with unique names. It is bad practice to reference container names in a stack. The service name is in the `docker-stack.yaml` file. If you are looking to create a docker stack with persistent volumes, it is better to create a persistent `volume` instead. `docker volume create [OPTIONS] [NAME]` [Docker volume create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)

You can also create it when you start your stack in your `docker-stack.yaml`. All containers spawn from my-service will use the same shared volume.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  my-service:
    image: my-service:latest
    volumes:
       - my-data:/usr/share/mydata

volumes:
  my-data
```

You may also reference an externally-created volume (with `docker volume create my-data`) with this instead:

```yaml
volumes:
  my-data:
    external: true
```